# param check pentaho report

Tags: report, pentaho

Estoy intentando insertar un parámetro tipo check en el informe pero lo que me muestra es un campo de texto. Lo que intento es que me aparezca un check al que le pueda poner un valor por defecto. Depende de ese check se harán otras actuaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso no ha código, lo único que puedo subir es la foto para mostrar la forma en la que intento hacer el parámetro.

Así es como me aparece en el report.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo

Comment: Hola Lorenzo. Lo estás intentando rellenando únicamente el campo de Display Type? Qué texto es el que te imprime (podríamos verlo)? Gracias

Comment: Buenas, he hecho una captura para que se vea como sale en la imagen. No me deja rellenar solo el Display Type. Hay que tener algún valor seleccionado, yo creo que el mas adecuado es el Boolean. Decir que ese check no tiene que depender de ningún origen de datos ni campo externo. Su función es hacer ciertos cambios en el informe según este marcado o no.